Liquibase - CICD pipeline failure
Question:
Azure CICD pipeline is failing with the below error. There hasnt been any recent changes to the environment/YAML. The "Replace tokens in Liquibase properties" step in the Deploy stage is failing.
Error:
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: chdir to cwd ("/home/liquibase") set in config.json failed: no such file or directory: unknown
##[error]Exit code 126 returned from process: file name '/usr/bin/docker', arguments 'exec -i -u 1001  -w /home/liquibase abcd123456789bdbdbdb /__a/externals/node/bin/node /__w/_temp/containerHandlerInvoker.js'.
YAML File:

